# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type results is not part of the model for the current context.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have seen all threads about this and tried everything and still get the exception.
i am trying to add these data i get from api to my database every 30sec

```
{"response_code":0,"results":[{"category":"Science & Nature","type":"multiple","difficulty":"hard","question":"Which of the following is the term for &quot;surgical complications resulting from surgical sponges left inside the patient&#039;s body?","correct_answer":"Gossypiboma","incorrect_answers":["Gongoozler","Jentacular","Meupareunia"]}]}
```

this is the model.contex

```
 public partial class MyDatabaseEntities : DbContext
{

    public MyDatabaseEntities()
        : base("name=MyDatabaseEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
       modelBuilder.Entity<results>().ToTable("Trivia");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<results> Trivias { get; set; }
```

this is my model class

```
public class Trivia
{
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "response_code")]
     public int response_code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName= "results")]
    public List<results> results { get; set; }
}


public  class results
    {

        public int QID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]   
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "difficulty")]  
        public string Difficulty { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "question")]
        public string Question { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "correct_answer")]  
        public string Correct_answer { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "incorrect_answer")]  
        public List<string> incorrect_answer { get; set; }
    }
```

}
this is my api call class

```
public static void schedulePhase()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(GetQuestion);
        timer.Interval = 30000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

        public static async void GetQuestion(object x, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1");
                var question = new Trivia();
                question = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Trivia>(response);
                var test = new results();
                test = question.results[0];
            
                if (question != null)
                {
                    MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities();
                    dc.Trivias.Add(test);
                    
                    dc.SaveChanges();

                }
```

this is my table

```
[QID]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Category]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Type]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Difficulty]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Question]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Correct_answer]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[incorrect_answer] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Trivia] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QID] ASC)
```

);
and this is the connection string

```
<add name="MyDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=JURGEN;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

now i know its not the connection string since in the same MYDATABASEENTITY i use the user model for login/registration form in the same project and it run perfectly.
anyone had same problem?
also i dont know why the worng_answer is null
[![api2obj][1]][1]

Comment: Maybe this: `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Nope didnt do it

Comment: Are you configuring the schema? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: @GeneralMac I dont think so man. i just want to add the api response(results) to the table